# Is it acceptable and safe to pthread_join myself?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, pthreads

I've got a setup something a bit like this:

```
void* work(void*) { while (true) {/*do work*/} return 0;}

class WorkDoer
{
private:
    pthread_t id;
public:
    WorkDoer() { pthread_create(&id, NULL, work, (void*)this); }
    void Shutdown() { pthread_join(id, NULL); /*other cleanup*/ }
}
```

There's some cases where `Shutdown()` is called from the main thread, and some other cases where I want to call shutdown from within the thread itself (returning from that thread right after).

The documentation for `pthread_join()` says that it will return a `EDEADLK` if the calling thread is the same as the one passed.

My question is: Is that an okay thing to do, and if so is it safe? (thus ignoring the join fail, because I'll be nicely ending the thread in a moment anyways?) Or, is it something that should be avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly call `pthread_join()` from the running thread itself, and as you have found out the call itself will handle it properly giving you an error code. However, there are a few problems:

1. It doesn't make any sense because the join won't join anything. It will merely tell you that you are doing something wrong.
2. The thread itself won't exit upon calling `pthread_join()` on itself.
3. Even if the thread exists, its state won't be cleaned up properly. Some other thread (i.e. your application's main thread) should call `pthread_join()` unless the thread was created as “detached”.

So in other words this approach is as acceptable as a bug in your program.

As a solution I would recommend to revisit the design and make sure that `Shutdown()` is called from the right place and at the right time. After all, the name “shutdown” doesn't make a lot of sense here because it doesn't shutdown a thing. What it does is merely waiting for a thread to finish and cleans up its state after that happens.

When you want to end the worker thread, either return from the thread routine or call [`pthread_exit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html). Then make sure that whoever started a thread cleans things up by calling `pthread_join()`.

If you want to force the thread to stop, consider using [`pthread_kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) to signal a thread or, alternatively, implement some sort of message passing that you can use to "tell" thread to stop doing whatever it is doing.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

```
   The pthread_join() function may fail if:

   EDEADLK
          A deadlock was detected or the value  of  thread  specifies  the
          calling thread.
```

I would say use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let the thread call `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` and then exit. No need to call `pthread_join()` then anymore and risking to have it fail.

Comment: This approach frequently leads to „cleanup problems”. If detached thread  refers to some memory, even to static objects, and main ends before detached thread ends, various corruptions happen (and coredump isn't rare). It's better to properly cleanup and join.

Comment: @Mekk: ... or just leave `main()` (which from the threading perspective is just another thread beyond the others) by calling `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: Who is to execute destructors for global and static objects in such a case? And atexits in more C-ish code?

Comment: @Mekk: That's all done when the process, that is its last thread ends.

Comment: Believe me: this „process ending" phase is much more complicated than it seems, at least in case your app has various threads which both need to finish some jobs, and use some static or global resources while doing that. I've analysed many "ending-phase" crashes. Explicitly joining threads (after notifying them that they must end) makes this much more manageable. Of course: if the thread is self-sufficient, doesn't use shared resources, and no one cares whether it finishes before or after peers, it can detach.